# Adding values from one array depending on occurrences of values in another array

Tags: python

Cant Really bend my mind around this problem I'm having:

say I have 2 arrays

```py
A = [2, 7, 4, 3, 9, 4, 2, 6]

B = [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7]
```

what I'm trying to do is that if a value is repeated in array B (like how 1 is repeated 3 times), those corresponding values in array A are added up to be appended to another array (say C)

so C would look like (from above two arrays):

```py
C = [13, 12, 12]
```

Also sidenote.. the application I'd be using this code for uses timestamps from a database acting as array B (so that once a day is passed, that value in the array obviously won't be repeated)

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: do you accept solutions with pandas?

Comment: sure, if it works im also down to learn

Comment: i don't understand how can I create C array. Please explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without pandas, using only `itertools` `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

C = [sum( a for a,_ in g) for _,g in groupby(zip(A,B),key = lambda x: x[1])]
```

yields:

```
[13, 12, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this
Say you put those arrays in a DataFrame. This does the job:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( 
    {
        'A': [2, 7, 4, 3, 9, 4, 2, 6],
         'B': [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7]
    }
)

df.groupby('B').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure python solution, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

A = [2, 7, 4, 3, 9, 4, 2, 6]
B = [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(zip(A, B), lambda k: k[1]):
    out.append(sum(v for v, _ in g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[13, 12, 12]
```